# Need help for array in java

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse

I'm studying this code.

```
import java.util.*;
public class JavaRandomMath {


    public static void main (String [] args)
    {


        Random rand = new Random();

        int freq[] = new int [5];

        for (int roll = 0; roll <= 5; roll++)
        {

            ++freq[1 + rand.nextInt(4)];

        }


        System.out.println("Face\tFrequency");


    for (int face = 0; face < freq.length; face++)
        {

            System.out.println(face + "\t" + freq[face]);

        }   


    }

}
```

I tried to understand this on my own and I can pretty understand the rest aside from this one line

`++freq[1 + rand.nextInt(4)];`

which is located in the first for loop.

I tried to use a breakpoint there to see what's happening behind. What I can understand from the debugger is that every time the first for loop LOOPS, the indices of the freq array is assigned a new value by the random.nextInt.

What I can't understand there is the whole line. The ++freq is really confusing to me. It looks like it's incrementing? and after the ++freq is a bracket [ ] that has this inside

`1 + rand.nextInt(4)`

I already read the docs of the random class in java. The 1 there maybe used to add on the generated number, but why does it need to be inside this [ ], and what does ++freq mean before [ ]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assessment is pretty correct.
You should remove adding 1 to the nextInt() call to keep the range of random numbers between 0..4 inclusive and stay within the bounds of your freq array.
Change it to: `++freq[rand.nextInt(4)];`

`rand.nextInt()` is randomly selecting the element in the array by randomly calculating which index to access (random number from 0 to 4).

The ++freq[index] is equivalent to the statement: Select the element from the freq array at index and then increment the value at that index by 1.

As an example. When you first declare freq:  `int freq[] = new int[5];` you will have an array of all 0's: `freq[] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}`

Then, in the loop you have this statement: `++freq[rand.nextInt(4)];` 
Let's assume `rand.nextInt(4)` randomly chooses 3.

```
++freq[3];
```

Recall the array was initialized to all zeros, so `freq[3]`, at this point = 0, or:

```
freq[3] = 0;
```

And finally, the ++ is a post-increment operator and will have the effect of incrementing the current value of freq[3] by 1, or:

```
 ++feq[3]; is equivalent to:
 freq[3] = freq[3] + 1; is equivalent to:
 freq[3] = 0 + 1; is equivalent to:
 freq[3] = 1;
```

Hope that adds some clarity.

Comment: _the code within the [] is randomly selecting the element in the array by randomly calculating which index to access (1 + a random number 0 to 4)._  Thanks for this. So the `[1 + rand.nextInt(4)];` acts as the index that makes sense to me now. So that's the reason why I do have an out of bound exception when I tried to make the random number from 0-5.

Comment: _The ++freq[index] is equivalent to the statement: Select the element from the freq array at index and then increment the value at that index by 1._ So this means that the elements are incremented randomly because the index is generated between 0-4 4 is exclusive but because I have 1 inside the `++freq[1 + rand.nextInt(4)];` the loop can access now the 4th index? Am I correct?

Comment: Because the array starts it's index at 0, and you initialize it to a size limited to 5 (new int [5]). So, the array goes from freq[0] to freq[4]. If you attempt to access freq[5] you will get an indexOutOfBounds exception. If you want to keep the array at a max length of 5, then you should change and limit the nextInt() call to 3: 1 + nextInt(3) , which will be a total max of 4.

Comment: I updated the answer to include the array bounds for more clarity.

Comment: Thank you so much @pczeus! I can't upvote your answer yet but I'm still thankful.

Answer (score 2):

The line could be more clearly written as:

```
int face = 1 + rand.nextInt(4);
freq[face] += 1;
```

`nextInt(4)` returns a value from 0..3 inclusive, so 1 is added to the result (most dice don't have a 0 face).

`++freq[i]` pre-increments by one the value in the `freq` array at index `i`.